# Single iOS subview within multiple ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have single continuously running subview (a MetalView running lots of shader code) that I would like to stay on top of multiple iOS container view controllers as I toggle between those view controllers.  Is there any way to do this without disturbing my running MetalView?

Comment: Have you tried making your root view controller with your metal view on top and rest as a container view? So you can show your view controllers in that container view?

Comment: Make the metal view your window's last subview?